# PHP to get value from DOMDocument (loadXML)

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am using a web-service (curl) to verify a value. Everything works fine despite the fact that I cannot store (and compare) the answer in a variable. I am using a PHP class `(XY.PHP)`. So I send the request from `AA`. PHP and should get the answer there. `Print_r($doc->firstChild->textContent)` works fine but I cannot store the answer. Any Idea? Thanks in advance.

```
AA.php
require 'includes/XY.php';
...
 $verify->VerifyIt();
        if ($verify === "StatusCode:30") {
        $text = "<p> okay</p>";          
        echo $text;   }  

XY.php
...
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($result);
print_r($doc->firstChild->textContent);                 
return $doc->firstChild->textContent;
```

Comment: `$verify` is an object, it can't be equal "StatusCode:30"; Dunno how that should work

Comment: with print_r($doc->firstChild->textContent) I get the answer "StatusCode:30"... So I guess there should be a possibility to fetch the answer... even better would be to get the number 30.

Comment: I believe you might be running into one of PHP's "Magic Methods" __tostring http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: The "Magic Methods" did it but were not necessary...Thanks for the input. Solution: 
$var = print_r($doc->firstChild->textContent,true); 
return $var;